# Starting the python application in debug mode

Tags: kinto

How do i start the Kinto application in debug mode in VS code?
https://github.com/Kinto/kinto/tree/master

The recommended way to start the application is using the make serve command. However, it doesnot start the app in debug mode. I need to debug to observe a few variables in code.

I tried using the debug as pyramid application option in vs code, but it is complaining that the pyramid module is not found